# can we have multiple form in a single form in windows form application?

Tags: windows, forms

i want to create a single form and in that form want to other forms. I want 5 button in one form and on click of one buuton other form with grid will display with different data fetched on button click. 
Can i do that? if yes help me to proceed.

Comment: of course you can 
if(buton1.click)
you will add new form here
if(buton2.click)
you will ad new form like this..

Comment: check

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/show-multiple-form-main-form-37980.aspx

Comment: and this 

http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-mdi-form.htm

Comment: I do not want to add new form. I want two forms in a form. One form will have 5 button and other will have grid with submit button. now when i click any one of 5 button this form will get invisible and other form will displayed with grid. after clicking submit button this form will get invisible and previous one will display..

Comment: Use a UserControl instead.

Comment: @hans passant : can you please give me an code example. It will be help full to me. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows form. This will be your main form. Assuming your using Visual Studio this is realatively easy. Once you have your main form up, drag and drop a user controller onto your form. Have your main form contain the 5 buttons,and your data grid on the other form.